# GWT compiler isn't allowing 'default' as a javascript object property in my JSNI block

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, jsni, facebook-instant-games

I'm porting my Java LIBGDX game to Javascript. There's some JSNI code that looks something like this:

```
private native void hello()
/*-{
    var object1 = {default: 'foo', b: 42};
    console.log(object1.default);
}-*/;
```

GWT refuses to compile this, giving me this error:

```
      [ERROR] Line 38: invalid property id
>       var object1 = {default: 'foo', b: 42, c: {}};
> ------------------------^
```

I tried the same code in native Javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and it works fine.

I'm guessing 'default' is some kind of keyword that GWT isn't allowing but I need to use it, because its expected by the interface I need to send the object to, specifically the Facebook Instant SDK and its [LocalizableContent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/fbinstant6.2#localizablecontent) object.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a string rather than an identifier:

```
private native void hello() /*-{
    var object1 = {'default': 'foo', b: 42};
    console.log(object1['default']);
}-*/;
```